# put.show()に対して反応がありません

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

Anaconda3(64bit) for windowsをインストールし、spyderで下記のコードを入力したところ、plt.plot(num,heoght)を入力した時点でコンソール上にグラフは表示されるのですが、plt.show()に対して新しいウィンドウが出ることもエラーメッセージも出ず反応がありません。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
num = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
height = np.array([100,300,200,500,400])
plt.plot(num,height)
plt.show()
```

コマンドプロンプトでPyQtのバージョンを調べたらPyQt5がインストールされており、
matplotlibのバックエンドの設定も調べましたが、qt5aggとなっていました。
ネット上で見つかるplt.show()に関する不具合の解決法のほとんどがバックエンドの設定に関するもので、他に打つ手が見つからず困っております。

ご助言いただけたら幸いです。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: すみません、Macの自動変換で put になってしまっていますが、コード上では　plt と入力しております。

Comment: 私の方で編集しましたが投稿者も質問内容を編集できます。誤字になっている箇所がありましたらご自身で編集してください。

Comment: コード例中の`bumpy`は`numpy`の誤記でしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

質問の内容は、`spyder`の正常な反応です。

`spyder`のコンソールは、標準ではiPythonを使っているので、そこにグラフが表示されるだけでウィンドウは出ません。

Anaconda Promptから実行するようにするか、`spyder`のコンソールの設定を修正して「外部ターミナルを使う」にすれば、plt.show()に対して新しいウィンドウが表示されます。しかし、`spyder`のコンソールは標準のものを使った方が便利だと思いますが。